# Should I tell a recruiter I may be interested in the same kind of offer later?

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, mental-health

I was contacted by a company for a position that doesn't interest me right now but will probably interest me in 6 months or so. Should I tell them? If yes, how should I explain it?

*Additional information:*

I started working at my current job a few months ago. It's my first job after a long period of not feeling well. Technically, it's a bit under my qualifications and the domain doesn't interest me much, but it's a no pressure job that pays a living wage, at walking distance from my place and I get along well with my co-workers. I've been feeling better ever since I started working there and wish to stay there for at least another 6 month, for mental health reasons.

A recruiter from a company contacted me with a job offer (better paid, more challenging and in a more interesting domain), which I plan on refusing.

Could it be useful at all to tell the recruiter that I will be interested in the same kind of offer in half a year? How do I phrase that without giving away my reasons?

Comment: NB : English isn't my first language, please tell me if any part of this text is unclear or badly worded. :)

Comment: You did fine. I've fixed the minor errors. FYI, "I wasn't [felling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felling) well" is only a concern that applies to lumberjacks :).

Comment: @RJFalconer How do you know I'm *not* a lumberjack ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to give a reason; just tell the recruiter you like the role but are not available for another 6 months, at which point you'd be open to considering the role. The recruiter will probably assume you are on a contract with 6 months' time remaining.

You are certainly not obligated to raise any health issues.

Comment: Hello, I ended up following your advise but I hesitate to accept this answer. Could you add a sentence to it answering to the "Should I told them I may be interested in the future?" part of the question? Thanks

Comment: Hi @GoldenSeagull I added the clause `, at which point you'd be open to considering the role`.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a good idea to keep the door open into the company by showing interest and rejecting in a polite manner, you don't want to burn bridges but realize that the offer at this very given moment *might* be your only chance to get that position. Someone else will be hired in the meantime and it's hard to say how that will impact future applicants.

I'd consider showing up for an interview, get a vibe for the company, the people who work there and the tasks at hand. Worst case you get to see if this is a company you'd like to work for in the future and the company gets to know you which is good if they like you, best case you decide that it's probably a good fit for you right now so you can consider jumping on board right away if you think it will have a positive impact on your mental health and finances.

If you don't want to go to an interview and at least consider the position right now simply thank the recruiter for the offer, say that you're not available for hire right now but the job looks very appealing and you hope to be in contact with them in the near future.